# AzCopy: "The transfer failed: Unable to write data to the transport connection"

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How to fix this error?

AzCopy is run for one file of about 1GB size like this under Administrator:

```
azcopy /source:PATHTOFILE /dest:https://PATHTOAZURECONTAINER /destkey:OURKEY /Pattern:ZIPFILE.zip /S /Y /V:PATHTOFILELOG.log
```

It fails with this error message:

> [2017/02/02 14:36:45.528+01:00][ERROR] FILENAMEHERE: The transfer failed: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

It copied successfully for small files.

Comment: It's probably due to network connectivity issue from your machine to Azure Storage. Could you try the same command in a machine with better network access?

Comment: AZCopy with in **re-startable mode** is supported for interruption caused by network or other issues during file transfer, which could help restart the transfer from the point of interruption instead of start from beginning, you could try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, [AzCopy with re-startable mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token/) is supported for interruption caused by network or other issues during file transfer, and which could make it restart the transfer from the point of interruption. We could write/run PowerShell script and AzCopy to detect whether error occurs during uploading large file, and if transfer failed, we could run the same azCopy.exe command to resume failed transfers in script until transfer success.